# Move Values into next Column

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table (The structure is fixed) which contains 24 Fields H0-H23 representing the hours of the day. In one of these columns there will be an 'M'. Once the 'M' has been found (Say in H13) then I want to swap the value in H13 for the Value in H14 (The field next to it) and swap the Value in H14 for H13. So in this example (I have limited it to 6 fields for clarity)

Null, Null, T, T, M, S, F

Would change to

Null, Null, T, T, S, M, F

What is the most efficient way to do this? Thank you

NOTE: I understand Update queries, The main problem is that I need to find the position of the 'M' without doing 24 case statements if possible

Comment: Change your data structure to have 24 rows of data instead of 24 columns.  Analytical queries such as ***"which hour is the 'M' in?"*** will then become significantly quicker/simpler.  *(Keeping your existing structure you either need to write a query to temporarily transform it in to multiple rows, or write a very long set of CASE statements.)*

Comment: Thank you for you comment, unfortunately this is not possible with this dataset (Existing system). I am literally 'stuck' with the current schema. Do you think it a better idea to pivot the data, find the M and then unpivot it? or should I use the case statement approach?

Comment: I like the idea of pivot--update--unpivot. I'd be interested in seeing the performance diff between that and cases.

Answer (score 0):

As you can't change the data-structure, you're stuck with a lot of CASE statements...

```
UPDATE
  yourTable
SET
  H00 = CASE m_hour                  WHEN 00 THEN H01 ELSE H00 END,
  H01 = CASE m_hour WHEN 00 THEN H00 WHEN 01 THEN H02 ELSE H01 END,
  H02 = CASE m_hour WHEN 01 THEN H01 WHEN 02 THEN H03 ELSE H02 END,
  H03 = CASE m_hour WHEN 02 THEN H02 WHEN 03 THEN H04 ELSE H03 END,
  ...
  H23 = CASE m_hour WHEN 22 THEN H22 WHEN 23 THEN ??? ELSE H23 END
FROM
(
  SELECT
    primary_key,
    CASE WHEN H00 = 'M' THEN 00
         WHEN H01 = 'M' THEN 01
         ...
    END AS m_hour
  FROM
    yourTable
)
  AS lookup
WHERE
  lookup.primary_key = yourTable.primary_key
```

You could shorten the sub-query CASE by doing something like this instead:

```
CHARINDEX('M', H00 + H01 + H02 + ... + H23, 0) - 1   AS m_hour
```

But that would also add some CPU load as a price for shortening the code, and doesn't get rid of the 24 CASE statements in the UPDATE.

Comment: I created the following, seems to work ok and is pretty quick:

Comment: SELECT HourDay --DD_ID, HourDay, Code
    FROM 
       (SELECT DD_ID, H0, H1,H2,H3,h4,h5,h6,h7,h8,h9,h10,H11,H12,H13,H14,H15,H16,H17,H18,H19,H20,H21,H22,h23 FROM [Tbl_DutyDetails] where DD_ID=@DD_ID) p
    UNPIVOT
       (Code FOR HourDay IN ( H0, H1,H2,H3,h4,h5,h6,h7,h8,h9,h10,H11,H12,H13,H14,H15,H16,H17,H18,H19,H20,H21,H22,h23)) AS unpvt
       where Code ='M')